# How to find a file which is having size more than the specified limit using python

Tags: python, file

How to find a file inside a folder, where the file size should be greater than the specified limit.

```
for root,dirs,files in os.walk('/mnt/usbdrive/data'):
    for file in files:
        if os.stat( '/mnt/usbdrive/data/').st_size >= 1020.0:
            s3C.upload_file(os.path.join(root,file),BUCKET_NAME,file)
        else:
            print("no files found")
print ("data available")
```

Comment: You only take the size of the root directory, not the file. Also, what's your question?

Comment: `file_size_in_bytes = os.path.getsize("/mnt/usbdrive/data/file_name.ext")` should give you the size

Comment: I need to upload the files which are greater than 1020 bytes

Comment: @user5173426 I have several files with different name. So, I can't specify the filename here. correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Nithya you could use it like I suggested in the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `os.path.getsize`:

```
for root,dirs,files in os.walk('/mnt/usbdrive/data'):
    for file in files:
        if os.path.getsize(file) >= 1020.0:
            s3C.upload_file(os.path.join(root,file),BUCKET_NAME,file)
        else:
            print("no files found")
print ("data available")
```

EDIT:

```
import os
thePath = os.getcwd()
theFiles = list(os.listdir(thePath))

theDict = dict()
for something in theFiles: #Calculate size for all files here.
    theStats = os.stat(something)
    theDict[something] = theStats

for item in theDict:
    if theDict[item].st_size > 1020:
        print("File: {}, size greater than 1020, Uploading to s3 ..".format(item))
        s3C.upload_file(os.path.join(root,file),BUCKET_NAME,file)
    else:
        print("File {}, size less than 1020".format(item))
```

OUTPUT (from my `dir` and with commented `s3C.upload_file()` method:

```
File: .idea, size greater than 1020, Uploading to s3 ..
File: celebs.jpg, size greater than 1020, Uploading to s3 ..
File data.csv, size less than 1020
File: dum.jpg, size greater than 1020, Uploading to s3 ..
File: dummy.jpg, size greater than 1020, Uploading to s3 ..
File example2.csv, size less than 1020
```

Comment: I get this error:  `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified:`

Comment: I have one file less than 1020 bytes and one more than 1020 bytes

Comment: @Nithya line 2, instead of os.getcwd()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188035/discussion-between-nithya-and-user5173426).

Comment: I had to replace os.getcwd() with os.chdir(path) or run the code from the current working directory. Thanks for your help